# Some of us + Noun

Tags: nouns

I don't know why we can use **Some of us + Noun** like this:

> **Some of us boys** are planning to drive throughout the country during
>   the summer holidays.

Can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 6):

It's simply a way to clarify who the plural pronoun *us* is referring to.

For example, my daughter might say:

> *Some of us are going to the mall after school*.

and, as a concerned parent, I'll want to know who "us" refers to.

But she could instead say:

> *Some of us band members are going to the mall after school*.

to clue me in on who she's talking about.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched on google and bing, and no results made me satisfied.

Comment: The pronoun 'we' is rather ambiguous in English (you and me, you and me and other people, me and some other people, who may or may not be present), so it's common to say things like "we boys are going ..." to remove the ambiguity. When you put "some of" in front of this construction, it becomes accusative, so you get "some of us boys are going ...".

Answer (score 3):

Inserting the noun tends to mark a *contrast* of some sort. So if you say:

> "Some of us boys are planning X"

there's often an implication of e.g. "...as opposed to the girls, who are planning Y".